# python dns update keyring object

Tags: python, dns

I'm trying to update a record in a dns server's zone using python, but i'm running into key issues.

This key work fine on the command line using a command similar to `nsupdate -k Ktest.com.+165+48236.key -v update.txt` -- So i know the dns server is OK with that key being used.

This is all test / dummy values so i'm posting the key string also

```
print "Updating zone [%s] record [%s] on dns host [%s] with new ip [%s]" % (zone, record, dns_host, new_ip)
keyring = dns.tsigkeyring.from_text({record : key})
print ""
print key
print ""
print keyring
print ""
update = dns.update.Update(record, keyring = keyring, keyname = record, keyalgorithm = 'hmac-sha512')
update.replace(record, 300, 'A', new_ip)
```

---

Output:

---

Updating zone [test.com] record [auth.test.com] on dns host [127.0.0.1] with new ip [123.123.123.123]

```
Q3oiZUnS83s9+8bBWwn+5ZMfj/qHwAWVuAt2Zck1YhYUygPeTwkKbXjV 6Wj+cIf/2IRdjv5OEDUrrA/orGAlZw==


{<DNS name auth.test.com.>: 'Cz"eI\xd2\xf3{=\xfb\xc6\xc1[\t\xfe\xe5\x93\x1f\x8f\xfa\x87\xc0\x05\x95\xb8\x0bve\xc95b\x16\x14\xca\x03\xdeO\t\nmx\xd5\xe9h\xfep\x87\xff\xd8\x84]\x8e\xfeN\x105+\xac\x0f\xe8\xac`%g'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./service_tester.py", line 122, in <module>
    check_nodes(config)
  File "./service_tester.py", line 107, in check_nodes
    check_dns(record_name, record_items['zone'], record_items['failover_type'],      record_items['key'], record_items['good_nodes'], record_items['dns_host'])
  File "./service_tester.py", line 69, in check_dns
    update_dns(zone, record, dns_server, good_hosts[0], key)
  File "./service_tester.py", line 44, in update_dns
    response = dns.query.tcp(update, dns_host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns/query.py", line 323, in tcp
    one_rr_per_rrset=one_rr_per_rrset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns/message.py", line 786, in from_wire
    reader.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns/message.py", line 727, in read
    self._get_section(self.message.additional, adcount)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns/message.py", line 679, in _get_section
    self.message.first)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns/tsig.py", line 163, in validate
    raise PeerBadKey
 dns.tsig.PeerBadKey
```

It looks to me like the keyring object isn't correct, but i don't know why it isn't so.

edit: the error on the dns server is: `not authoritative for update zone (NOTAUTH)`

But if i do a `ndupdate -k keyfile -v update.txt` it works just dandy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be:

`update = dns.update.Update(record, keyring = keyring, keyname = record, keyalgorithm = 'hmac-sha512')`

Should have been

`update = dns.update.Update(zone, keyring = keyring, keyname = record, keyalgorithm = 'hmac-sha512')`

The error message is pretty confusing, as it's saying it can't update the zone on the dns server, not that the client actually tried to update that zone.